# AS3: How to catch the event sent from subchild class?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, children

[image]

I thought it's a straight forward work but it isn't :(.
You can see now how I designed my code. 
Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the dispatchEvent call in other method, not in the constructor. Maybe on an ADDED_TO_STAGE handler function.

When you create the Event instance, you have to pass another parameter indicating that the event will be propagated (it is called bubbles in the reference)

```
dispatchEvent("ShipCreated", true);
```

Comment: Thank you 
That was the problem :(. Stupid, stupid me. I had to do : addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, checkShip);
  }
  private function checkShip(e:Event):void
  {
   dispatchEvent(new Event("ShipCreated"));
  }

Answer (score 4):

Add the event listener to `child3`. `child2.child3` won't work.

```
child3 = new Child3();
child3.addEventListener("ShipCreated", onShipCreated); 
child2.addChild(child3);
```

If you want to access children of `child2` you will have to use `getChildAt` or `getChildByName` to get it. For example :

```
child2.getChildAt(0).addEventListener(...);
```

Though using child3 directly is much better in this case.

Also you are dispatching from the constructor of `Child3` which happens before the event handler is added. So your handler will not be called. You need to dispatch after the event handler is added for it to work.

Comment: child3.addEventListener("ShipCreated", onShipCreated); - not working;
child2.getChildAt(0).addEventListener("ShipCreated", onShipCreated); - not working

Comment: Not working as in your handler isn't called? That is because you are dispatching in the constructor and the event handler is added after the object is created. Move the dispatchEvent to another function.

Comment: Barış I tried this way just to check if I can do it child2.getChildAt(0).addEventListener(...); but nothing happens. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys:

That solved the problem

```
    public function Child3()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, checkShip);
    }
    private function checkShip(e:Event):void
    {
        dispatchEvent(new Event("ShipCreated"));
    }
```